# How to Get List of Table Columns?

Tags: model

How can I get all columns all or all attributes on product if there is no data on it?

For example this one : [image]

How can I get the list of (post_id, name, url_key, post_content, tags, status, featured_image, created_at, updated_at).

Comment: May I know which Magento version are you using also Please provide any code you have

Comment: I'm using Magento 2.3.1 @poojansharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add ProductRepository in your custom module __construct

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository)
{
   $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

Then call a getProductAttribute function with argument SKU. Below is the code for the same.

```
public function getProductAttribute($sku)
    {
        $new= array();
        $product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        foreach($attributes as $a)
        {
            $new[$a->getName()] = $product->getData($a->getName());
        }
      return $new; 
    }
```

Note: before execute code make sure run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```